# Huge delay between Amazon SNS message and Lambda invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have configured a SNS topic with 2 subscriptions: Email and a Lambda function. Everything worked fine until yesterday (04/04/2016). When I publish a message to the SNS Topic the Email notification arrives fast. But the invocation of the Lambda function happens eventually but hours later.

Nothing has changed about the function, IAM, etc. This is happening in the Ireland region and I don't see any errors in CloudWatch logs and metrics.

Any idea why this happens and how I can prevent this and/or monitor this?

Comment: Sounds like something you should open an AWS support ticket for.

Answer (score 1):

Could be throttling.  Your account is only allowed to run a certain number of lambdas concurrently (I think 1000 is the default limit now).  If SNS triggers a lambda and it gets rejected because you have 1000 lambdas running, SNS will wait and retry and then wait longer and retry.

When we have bursts of activity we have seen our SNS triggers delayed by 30-90 minutes.  Supposedly it will keep trying for up to 6 hours.

You can check this in the console by going to the main dashboard for the lambda service.  It shows you a graph of how many lambdas have recently been throttled.